# Grunt server and scss source map: not serving the scss files (404)

Tags: google-chrome, sass, gruntjs, yeoman, source-maps

I'm quite new to **yeoman** / **grunt** / **bower** and in the last 3 days my brain started to smell like bacon.

I've generated a basic webapp with *yeoman Webapp generator (0.4.9)*.

I'm using the *scss* version of bootstrap  and I've managed to make **source mapping** working with my Chrome Canary adding `sourcemap: 'true'` under sass/server/options in my *gruntfile*

```
sass: {
        options: {
            includePaths: [
                'bower_components'
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        server: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }],
            options: {
                sourceComments: 'map',
                sourcemap: 'true'
            }

        }
    } ...
```

So when I inspect the css rules under the styles panel of Chrome I correctly get a link to the original scss files of bootstrap.

The problem comes with my custom scss files that I've added in `app/style/`. 
In here I have a `main.scss` file from where I import the bootstrap **scss** files and my cusotm scss files (still under `app/styles`).

The bootstrap scss files are served correctly while all my custom scss files are not found (included the main.scss).
When launching  `grunt serve` Chrome is looking for them (for example) at `http://localhost:9000/app/styles/main.scss` generating a **404** error. The files are actually served correctly at `http://localhost:9000/styles/main.scss`.

**QUESTION:**
Considering the amount of new knowledge/tasks I'm VERY confused, what's going on? Is this problem coming from the server, the source map, the autoprefixer, the livereload or what else?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, watch this video: http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/07/23/sass-source-maps-chrome/

In short: You have to map local scss folder (Add folder to workspace in Sources tab) to virtual server scss file. Then You can edit it straight from Chrome :-)